# How can I make git detect all renamed files from directory

Tags: git, github

I have done many changes in my git repo along with renaming to uppercases. After commit&push everything was ok but names stay in lowercase.

Okay so I can add them to commit by `git mv dir/dir2/file dir/dir2/File` (They are starting from uppercase on local folder, but git recognizes them only in lowercase) but I have many of them so I would like to avoid doing that one by one.

I thought about some bash command but im currently on windows mobaxterm and it doesnt work well with it.

So can I somehow tell git to recheck all directories and subdirectories for renames and add it to commit?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are kind of barking at the wrong tree. The problem there is not _really_ on git but on your OS. I bet you are using windows, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the case insensitivity

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

It's recommend to enable it afterwards.

Comment: It recognized correctly, but files end up in 'added status' not renamed which results in duplication

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working bash? Even the one that is coming with git for windows?  You might try this (bash 4.0 trick):

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | while read file; do new_path=$( echo "${file,,}" ); git mv "$file" temp; git mv temp "$new_path"; done
```

I guess you should try prepending echo to the git mv commands to make sure that the sequence of git mv commands is correct.... when you are sure, remove the echos and it should work.